# Detect when animation is finished (AnimationListener)

Tags: android, kotlin, lottie

I can programatically start an Animation with lottie in Kotlin but I am struggling to create an AnimationListener. How exactly do I do that?

First, I tried it with an if-statement via the animation_view.progress but that did not work.

```
        textChanger.setOnClickListener{


                   animation_view.setAnimation("data.json")
                   animation_view.playAnimation()
                   animation_view.loop(false)
        }
```

I would like it to detect when the animation has finished so I can e.g. make a Toast. Are there any good lottie documentations for Kotlin?

Thanks for the help, just starting out with Android and Kotlin.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can check [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/Animator.AnimatorListener).

Try using this code :

```
animation_view.addAnimatorListener(object:Animator.AnimatorListener {
    override fun onAnimationRepeat(animation: Animator?) {
        TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
    }


    override fun onAnimationEnd(animation: Animator?) {
        TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
    }

    override fun onAnimationCancel(animation: Animator?) {
        TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
    }

    override fun onAnimationStart(animation: Animator?) {
        TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to do this in, for example React Native - Typescript lottie?

That compiles down to Android + iOs, so I'm not really interested in the Kotlin code for this because my codebase has 0 Kotlin, only typescript.

I'm guessing there might be a Animation Listener implementation for Lottie's react native library but i'm struggling to find it.